# Cuspidal stable curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, flatness

I have seen this many times but never know a rigorous proof. In a flat family of stable curves, if an elliptic tail is contracted then we get a cuspidal curve, if an elliptic
bridge is contracted, we get a tacnodal curve. I understand the reason behind this ( arithmetic genus & Euler characteristic ). How do you know that if we contracted a
subcurve in the central fiber (assume the other fibers are smooth), then the resulting family
is still flat ? What condition guarantees this?

Comment: Any dominant morphism $f:X \to Y$ with $Y$ a smooth curve and $X$ integral is flat. This follows from the fact that a module over a dvr is flat iff it is torsion free.